# How complete a matrix with the information of a file in C?

Tags: c

I'm learning C, but I have a problem with an exercise. I need to fill a matrix that I started with zeros, with the information of a file. The file contains some coordinates and I need to put in the matrix the numbers that contain the file, but in the row of coordinates previous to which the file gives me.

For example, if I have this file:

```
2,3 4 3 1
3,1 3 2 2
1,4 1 2 8
```

I need my final matrix to look like this:

```
0 0 0 1 2 8
0 0 4 3 1 0
3 2 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My code: (that only opens the file and creates the matrix because I'm looking for information or examples, but I can not find anything useful)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
FILE *data;
data = fopen("example.txt","r");
if (data == NULL)
{                           
  printf("\nERROR\n");  
    return -1;
}
int row = 4;
int col = 6;
int matrix[row][col];
for (int x = 0; x < row; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y)
    {
        matrix[x][y]=0;
    }
}
fclose(data);
for (int x = 0; x < row; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y)
    {
        printf("[%d]",matrix[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be done in many different ways. You need to try coding it yourself and in case you can't make it work, you can ask about problems with your code. Two function you could use are: `fgets` and `sscanf` There many examples on SO for use of these functions.

Comment: Example: Assume you have read a line into `buf` then code like this could be useful: `sscanf(buf, "%d,%d%n", &row, &col, &used)`

Comment: Sorry, you lost me with the conversion from file to matrix
what's the logic from
2,3 4 3 1
3,1 3 2 2
1,4 1 2 8 
to
0 0 0 1 2 8
0 0 4 3 1 0
3 2 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 and cannot format correctly in this comment.

Comment: @BobRun I think OP means that the format is "row, column value1 value2 …" So the first two numbers is the starting point and then comes a number of values. Like: `matrix[row][column] = value1; matrix[row][column + 1] = value2; matrix[row][column + 2] = value3; . . .` It seems however that row/column starts from 1 instead of 0 as we normally do...

Comment: @4386427 Ok got it, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try to solve problems by myself and only ask for specific questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this. If you know you will have 2 coordinates and 3 values per-line, then one of the easiest, and most robust ways of handling the read and parsing the data from each line, is to read each line into a buffer with `fgets` and then parse the line into the individual coordinates with `sscanf`.<sup>**1**</sup> While you could accomplish the same thing with a single call to `fscanf`, reading with `fgets` will insure you consume an entire line of data each time and allows independent validation of your (1) read of data from the file; and (2) the parsing of the data into your coordinates and values.

You then simply need to map your *coordinates* into valid C-indexes by subtracting `1` (remember arrays in C a *zero-based* not *one-based*), check to make sure your coordinates are valid so that writing 3 values beginning at your indexes do not write beyond the bounds of your array, and finally, loop writing your 3-values to the `x` row beginning at the `y` index.

A simple implementation could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NVAL    3   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define ROW     4
#define COL     6
#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line read with fgets */
    int matrix[ROW][COL] = {{0}};   /* 2D array initialized all zero */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {         /* read each line into buf  */
        int x, y, data[NVAL] = {0};         /* declare coords/data vars */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d,%d %d %d %d",  /* parse line into values   */
                    &x, &y, &data[0], &data[1], &data[2]) != 5) {
            fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
            continue;   /* skip to next line on error */
        }
        x = x - 1;  /* convert coords to zero based index for C */
        y = y - 1;
        if (x < ROW && y <= COL - NVAL) {   /* check valid indexes */
            for (int i = 0; i < NVAL; i++)  /* loop over each value */
                matrix[x][y++] = data[i];   /* write numbers to array */
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {         /* loop over rows */
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)       /* loop over cols */
            printf ("%2d", matrix[i][j]);   /* outputting values */
        putchar ('\n');                     /* tidy up with newline */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/matcoords.txt
2,3 4 3 1
3,1 3 2 2
1,4 1 2 8
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/matrix_data_at_coords <dat/matcoords.txt
 0 0 0 1 2 8
 0 0 4 3 1 0
 3 2 2 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**footnotes:**

**1.** Note: none of the `scanf` family provide any error reporting capability beyond succeed/fail. For fine-grained error reporting for numeric conversion, use the `strtoX` family of functions (e.g. `strtol, strtoul, strtod, etc...`)

Comment: Thank you very much, it has helped me a lot to understand how to obtain information from files, but I have a question, is there a way to obtain the maximum values ​​that the variables X and Y take and save them in variables such as int max_X and int max_Y?
for the example int max_X = 3 and int max_Y = 4.

Comment: Sure. Just declare `int maxx = 0, maxy = 0;` outside the read loop and each time you read `x` an `y`, test `if (x > maxx) maxx = x;` and `if (y > maxy) maxy = y;` After the read loop competes, `maxx` and `maxy` will hold the maximum values of `x` and `y`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char string[99];   
 FILE *data;
int row = 4;
int col = 6;
int y=0;
int matrix[row][col];
int matrixrow,position, s1 , s2 , s3 ;

for (int x = 0; x < row; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y)
    {
        matrix[x][y]=0;
    }
}

 data=fopen("example.txt"   ,"r");

 while( fgets( string , 10 , data))
 {
 // each row we expect int comma int space int space int space int space
 // first int is row , int after comma is position , next 3 ints are data to stuff at position
 matrixrow =(string[0]- '0')-1;  // substract 0 to get int
 position=(string[2]- '0')-2;
 s1=string[4]- '0';
 s2=string[6]- '0';
 s3=string[8]- '0';

 matrix[matrixrow][position+1]=s1;
 matrix[matrixrow][position+2]=s2;
 matrix[matrixrow][position+3]=s3;

 printf("\n\nfrom text file matrix");
 printf("\n%s", string);
 printf("\noutput");
 printf("[%d]", matrixrow);
 for( y=0 ; y<col-1 ; y++)
   printf("[%d]", matrix[matrixrow][y]);
}

printf("\n\nPrint whole matrix\n" );
 for (int x = 0; x < row; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y)
    {
        printf("[%d]",matrix[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


fclose(data);

}
```